# "FFmpeg was not found, spotdl can't continue" even though its installed using sudo apt-get install spotdl + it works if ran from terminal

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def getsong(ctx, *, songname):
    "get song in mp3 from song name"
    os.popen(f'spotdl {songname} -f "/home/pi/discordbot/output/{songname}.mp3"')
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fr'/home/pi/discordbot/output/{songname}.mp3'))
```

ffmpeg installed with sudo-apt get. works if ran from terminal
how to fix?

figured it out my self.
working code if it benefits anyone:

```
@bot.command()
async def getsong(ctx, *, songname):
    "get song in mp3 from song name"
    subprocess.Popen(f'spotdl -o "/home/pi/discordbot/output" --ffmpeg "/usr/bin/ffmpeg" {songname} --path-template "{songname}.mp3"', shell=True)
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fr'/home/pi/discordbot/output/{songname}.mp3'))
```

Comment: "works if ran from terminal" try using the full path of the executable. (Sidenote: you should be using `subprocess.Popen`)

Comment: i installed via sudo apt-get + thanks for the side note.
to clarify "works if ran from terminal" i mean if i run spotdl from terminal there is no error

Comment: Your path probably isn't configured correctly in python. Are you using virtualenv? What command did you run in terminal to get it to work?

Comment: i fixed it. it was i had to add --ffmpeg "path to ffmpeg"

Answer (score 0):

Try use `subprocess.check_output` from subprocess, for example

```
@bot.command()
async def getsong(ctx, *, songname):
    # get song in mp3 from song name :D
    subprocess.check_output(f'spotdl {songname} -f "/home/pi/discordbot/output/{songname}.mp3"', shell=True)
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(f'/home/pi/discordbot/output/{songname}.mp3'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def getsong(ctx, *, songname):
    "get song in mp3 from song name"
    subprocess.Popen(f'spotdl -o "/home/pi/discordbot/output" --ffmpeg "/usr/bin/ffmpeg" {songname} --path-template "{songname}.mp3"', shell=True)
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fr'/home/pi/discordbot/output/{songname}.mp3'))
```

this is the fix. --ffmpeg is path to ffmpeg